# How to dynamically add th to the existing th using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can i add value to th dynamically using Jquery. I am looking to append the values to th Heading8 and  Heading9 after Heading7

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th>Heading2</th>
        <th>Heading3</th>
        <th>Heading4</th>
        <th>Heading5</th>
        <th>Heading6</th>
        <th>Heading7</th>           
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: `$('thead tr').append( $('<th />', {text : 'Heading8'}) )`

Comment: If there re many tables in a page , and If I have to append this only to a specific table, then how can i achieve my requirement.

Comment: Give the table an ID

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `append`:

```
//adds new <th> Heading8 after Heading7
$('thead tr').append( $('<th />', {text : 'Heading8'}) )

//adds new <th> Heading9 after Heading8
$('thead tr').append( $('<th />', {text : 'Heading9'}) )
```

*EDIT*

Append to a specific table:

```
<thead>
  <tr id="selectMe">
    <th>Heading1</th>
    <th>Heading2</th>         
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Then use:

```
$('#selectMe').append( $('<th />', {text : 'Heading3'}) )
```

Comment: If there re many tables in a page , and If I have to append this only to a specific table, then how can i achieve my requirement.

Comment: Give each particular table an `id`, then select the table with jQuery by its `id`. Then use `append` like before.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('table thead th:last-child').after('<th>test</th>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your code helped me to achieve the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

> ```
> $('#tableId').append($('<th />', {text : 'Your Text'}))
> ```